# Parameter is not valid on Image read write to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, image, bitmap, arrays

I have an XML file that contains a Byte array as a string. (Microsoft Logo Gif Image)

```
  <CustomerLogo1>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</CustomerLogo1>
```

When I load the XML I pull the image in using the following function

```
   static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

i.e.

```
    CustomerLogo1 = GetBytes(xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[8].InnerText);
```

I then use the following function read it back

```
    public Bitmap byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        return new Bitmap(mem);
    }
```

However I get an error "Parameter is not valid" on new Bitmap(mem) comment

What I dont understand is whether its a problem with reading it, or it is a problem with what is written to disk. I am using the following functions to write the byte array, this is a parameter on the XML class.

```
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

To Save the XML I then save using

```
    public string SettingsToXMLString(Settings settings)
    {
        StringWriter Output = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(settings.GetType());
        s.Serialize(Output, settings);
        return Output.ToString();
    }
```

Many thanks Andrew

Comment: In `GetBytes`, why don't you just *use* `str.ToCharArray()` instead of manually measuring it out and copying it?

Comment: Also, where do you get "Parameter is not valid"? Which method? Which parameter? Additionally, are you sure `xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[8]` is exactly the element you want? I'd suggest grabbing it by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [System.Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to retrieve your binary data from an xml document. So your code should looks like this:

```
CustomerLogo1 = Convert.FromBase64String(xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[8].InnerText);
```

EDIT: And as Jim says, you should better access to xml element by their name instead of their current position in the document.